# How to disable socket.io 1.0 debugging?

Tags: socket.io, console-output

I've upgraded to socket.io 1.0 which now uses [visionmedia/debug](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug)

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuGoz.png]

It shows those messages even after `SET DEBUG=-*`

Comment: For me works with "EXPORT DEBUG=" on Mac OS terminal. Don't forget restart your node.js app

Comment: Also you can remove the environment variable DEBUG with "unset DEBUG".

Answer (score 2):

You can set the log level when configuring socket.io (version < .1.0).

Setting it to 0 will only outpout in the console on error. You could also use your own logger and have it disabled.

> log level defaults to 3
>
> The amount of detail that the server should output to the logger.
>
> 0 - error
>
> 1 - warn
>
> 2 - info
>
> 3 - debug

**Socket.io 1.0+**

Note that the logger confirmation has changed please see the [log differences](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#log-differences) and it is now using the [debug module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug).

Comment: From socket.io version 1.0 the logger configuration has changed. Official documentation: socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#log-differences

Answer (score 1):

You can set the log level as described in [the documentation](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO).

```
io  = require('socket.io').listen(app);
io.set('log level',0);
```

> - 0 - error
> - 1 - warn
> - 2 - info
> - 3 - debug

Comment: Logger configuration has change to environment variables and also SET is not longer available on socket.io version 1.0.
Socket.io logger documentation: http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#log-differences

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to node_modules folder
2. inside to open socket.io folder

   [image]
3. Click and open manager.js

   ```
    function Manager (server, options) {
       this.server = server;
       this.namespaces = {};
       this.sockets = this.of('');
       this.settings = {
       origins: '*:*', 
       log: false, 
       store: new MemoryStore, 
       logger: new Logger, 
       static: new Static(this), 
       heartbeats: true, 
       resource: '/socket.io', 
       transports: defaultTransports, 
       authorization: false, 
       blacklist: ['disconnect'], 
       'log level': 1, 
       'log colors': tty.isatty(process.stdout.fd)
     };
   ```

   **set log to false**

   Buzinga done  :-)

Comment: It gets the job done, and sometimes it is needed, but I wouldn't edit the source of a npm module. For one thing: this will normally be lost once you update to the next version of a package, also coworkers or production environments won't get this change either (on the overwhelming majority of cases, this directory is not on version control, etc.).